# `torch.cuda.Event()` throws error `TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`

Tags: python, constructor, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to measure the time of some code in torch, but am unable to instantiate `torch.cuda.Event`. The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.Event.html) doesn't suggest that any parameters are needed, and the same exact line is working on a different machine.

Uninstalling and reinstalling torch (using `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113` on Windows 10) didn't solve the problem.

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\streams.py", line 138, in __new__
    return super(Event, cls).__new__(
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

I'll appreaciate any help here!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Have you found any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem several times, on different machines. Each time, the program was runing on `cpu` and not `gpu` as it was supposed to. Ensuring that it was running on `gpu` solved the problem for me.

I didn't manage to find a solution to make it work on `cpu`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34666921)

Comment: I think it does answer the question. The line M A specifies `torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)` is correct, but works only if a GPU is available. `torch.cuda.Event` returns the error M A specified when no GPU is availble or used.

Answer (score 0):

These are possible problems comes in my mind in first sight, please check them,

- Check your `torch` installation `torch.cuda.is_available()`
- Does you `GPU` supports your `CUDA` version ?