# An issue with PyTorch's Event

Tags: python, machine-learning, inheritance, pytorch

I am using the following github code and it is initiating this error

```
class musterModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(musterModel, self).__init__()

        self.model = pedMondel(args.frames, vel=args.velocity, seg=args.seg, h3d=args.H3D, n_clss=3)
        ckpt = torch.load(args.ckpt, map_location=args.device)
        #ckpt = torch.load(args.ckpt, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
        self.model.load_state_dict(ckpt)
        self.model = self.model.to(args.device)
        #self.model = self.model.to(torch.device('cuda:0'))
        self.model.eval() 

str_t = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
end_t = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)


  

  str_t.record()
        if args.last2:
            x = x[:, :, -(args.lastn+30):] if args.forecast else x[:, :, -args.lastn:]
            pred = model(x.contiguous().half(), f.half(), v.half())
        else:
            pred = model(x.half(), f.half(), v.half())
        
        end_t.record()

        torch.cuda.synchronize()
        timimg.append(str_t.elapsed_time(end_t))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lambda-quad2/H line 308, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/home/lambda-quad2/H.py", line 166, in main
    str_t = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)
  File "/home/lambda-quad2/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/streams.py", line 164, in __new__
    return super(Event, cls).__new__(
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Any help what to do in this case? The str_t and end_t are defined in the above code

Comment: The error comes from `str_t = torch.cuda.Event(enable_timing=True)`. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with `musterModel`, but rather with how you're initializing `Event`.

Comment: I added the code involving the str_t. Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by initializing the Event.

Comment: It seems to be unrelated to the code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72278094/3775493 It may be better to open an issue in PyTorch's repo: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch